# How to use value in type syntax

Tags: typescript, oop, types

I want return type of my method is one of my class's properties (dynamically), how can i do this?

Something like this:

```js
interface IObject {
  [key: string]: any
}

class classX<T extends IObject> {
  public methodX(column: keyof T) {
    return (null as any) as T[`${column}`] // T['property']
  }
}
const varX = new classX<{ property: string }>()
varX.methodX('property') // expected type string

const varY = new classX<{ property: number }>()
varY.methodX('property') // expected type number
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to your method and use that to constrain both your parameter and return type:

```
interface IObject {
  [key: string]: any
}

class classX<T extends IObject> {
  public methodX<K extends keyof T>(column: K): T[K] {
    return (null as any) as T[K];
  }
}

const varX = new classX<{ property: string }>();
varX.methodX('property');

const varY = new classX<{ property: number }>();
varY.methodX('property');
```

<sup>[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIHkBGArCCzIDeAUMsgNoDWEAngFzIDOYUoA5gLoNwg3EC+xYggA2cRo2SjxjABoAeACrIIAD0ggAJpIw48YAHxFSyAA4BXTCOAJkAWwhgAFgHtNCgNIr1ELZOo0LjDIigYAFAguIuZ2IAweAJQMiuQeHMZkZFCO5lAgyGEg5iIiyOJlvAllkilpANwmgoLCLiDMyABucFCyyAC8yCAQAO5SYhIKhGZQLqbQYPRMLOzI-OEJxF09AHQOzm6yYQDkpjNzUAtHCQ0tbQRbAJr9gyNjMpPTs-OLRXaY0Kt1ptug9do5XO5jqcvhcaFc6kA)</sup>